# Difference between $\prod $ and $\bigotimes$

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

What is the exact difference between $\prod $ and $\bigotimes$ when both are taken over collection of sets?

e.g. $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a collection of sets. What are $$\prod_iA_i \text{ and }\bigotimes_iA_i.$$
$\prod$ is a Cartesian product. I have a feeling that so is $\bigotimes$.

This is related specially in cases of algebras.

Comment: The latter usually denotes the [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). That is an algebraic concept; I have never seen it used on arbitrary sets.

Comment: The usual monoidal structure on the category of sets is the cartesian one, where (finite) tensor products coincide with cartesian products.

Comment: In some algebraic literature the second one is defined as a subset of the first one: Each element of the direct sum contains only finite number of non-neutral components (factors).

Answer (score 2):

Since you include the measure-theory tag... sometimes, if $X_i$ is a set for each index $i \in I$, and $\mathcal A_i$ is a sigma-algebra on $X_i$, we may write
$$
\bigotimes_{i \in I} \mathcal A_i
\tag{*}$$
for the "product sigma-algebra" on the cartesian product set
$$
\prod_{i \in I} X_i
$$
In that case, certainly (*) is not the cartesian product.

Similarly, if $\mu_i$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal A_i$ I have occasionally seen
$$
\bigotimes_{i \in I} \mu_i 
$$
for the product measure.  Again, not the cartesian product.